# Exception encountered when calling layer "model" (type Functional)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_5" (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "gru_21" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 160, 160, 3)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "model_5" (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 160, 160, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

My data face this error **Can't solve this problem can someone help?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please ask questions only once, I suggest that you delete this question as your other question has a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned data dimensions to input suitable for learning mostly we removed duplicated or no sorted data and expand to match the model input. You will know that tf.squeeze() then tf.expand() will return the same shape as they know the original but tf.reshape() is not or using tf.Keras.layer.dense(). You may try UpSampling, DownSampling, and Zero padding but tf.squeeze() is faster since you using the same model.

Sample 1: tf.squeeze() also determined input saturation, extensive computed does not require at this layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        input = tf.constant( sample, shape=( inputs.shape[0], 1, 1 ) )
    
        return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
        
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
start = 3
limit = 12
delta = 3
sample = tf.range( start, limit, delta )
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( sample.shape[0], 1, 1, 1 ) )

print( "sample.shape: " )
print( sample.shape )
squeeze = tf.squeeze(sample)
print( "squeeze.shape: " )
print( squeeze.shape )
expand = tf.expand_dims(squeeze, axis=1)
expand = tf.expand_dims(expand, axis=1)
print( "expand.shape: " )
print( expand.shape )

layer = MyLSTMLayer( expand.shape[0], True, False )
print( "layer(expand): " )  
print( layer(expand) )
```

Output:

```
sample.shape:
(3, 1, 1, 1)
squeeze.shape:
(3,)
expand.shape:
(3, 1, 1)
layer(expand):
tf.Tensor(
[[[  0.63391364   3.29993     -3.571113  ]]

 [[  1.2678273    6.59986     -7.142226  ]]

 [[  1.9017409    9.89979    -10.713339  ]]], shape=(3, 1, 3), dtype=float32)

C:\Python310>
```

Sample 2: How about convolution Squeeze?

```
conv2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')
result_1 = conv2d_layer(sample)
squeeze = tf.squeeze(result_1)

print( squeeze )
```

Output:

```
[[7.86404922e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.06872266e+05 0.00000000e+00]
  [7.86435703e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.06876477e+05 0.00000000e+00]
  [7.86466406e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.06880758e+05 0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [7.91164062e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.07531219e+05 0.00000000e+00]
  [7.91194844e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.07535523e+05 0.00000000e+00]
  [7.91225547e+04 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
   1.07539719e+05 0.00000000e+00]]], shape=(158, 158, 32), dtype=float32)
```